# Scrollview boarder covered by content

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview, border

In my android app, I have a scrollview that displays a number of images. I have put a border around the scrollview but the images cover the border at the bottom as per image shows.
[image]

The code I am using for the the boarder is :-

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/instruction"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:background="@drawable/llbg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrolbar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
         <TableRow>
            <Imageview/>
            <Imageview/>    
        </TableRow>
        // A few more table rows in here
        
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the basic layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="15px"
    android:color="@color/black" />
<solid android:color="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

Is there a way to stop this?

The eml code being used

Comment: can you share your xml layout too?

Comment: I have added the xml code

Answer (score 1):

Add margin bottom of `15dp` which is border stroke width to immediate child of `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView>
   <!-- whatever your child of scroll view is, add margin bottom to that -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:marginBottom = "15dp"
    />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `android:layout_marginBottom="<<yourValue>>"` to your `ScrollView` ?
So it will be like

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:background="@drawable/llbg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrolbar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">
         <TableRow>
            <Imageview/>
            <Imageview/>    
        </TableRow>
        // A few more table rows in here
        
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```